# Keras input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 3 vs 4

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I'm training InceptionResnetV2 but I gor this error message

```
InvalidArgumentError
 input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 3 vs 4
     [[node sequential/inception_resnet_v2/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at C:\Labbb\inceptionResnetV2\4channel\InceptionResnetV2_4CHANNEL.py:137) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_37370]

Function call stack:
train_function
  File "C:\Labbb\inceptionResnetV2\4channel\InceptionResnetV2_4CHANNEL.py", line 137, in <module>
    callbacks=[reduce_lr])
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError:  input depth must be evenly divisible by filter depth: 3 vs 4
     [[node sequential/inception_resnet_v2/conv2d/Conv2D (defined at C:\Labbb\inceptionResnetV2\4channel\InceptionResnetV2_4CHANNEL.py:137) ]] [Op:__inference_train_function_37370]

Function call stack:
train_function
```

I merge rgb image and gray scale image to a RGBA 4-channel image

And I modify input_shape= 4-channel , classes = 7

```
base = applications.InceptionResNetV2(include_top=False, weights=None,input_shape=[img_height,img_width,4]) 

model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    base,
    tf.keras.layers.BatchNormalization(renorm=True),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(512, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.5),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    #tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='softmax') 
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(7, activation='softmax') 
    ])
  
model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=0.005, momentum=0.9),
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

How to fix this problem?

If I want to use 4-channel image for training, I need to build a InceptionResnetV2 model and modify input shape?

Or ImageDataGenerator only support 1 and 3 channel image?

Comment: According to the documentation, the channels number must be 3 "It should have exactly 3 inputs channels, and width and height should be no smaller than 75. E.g. (150, 150, 3) would be one valid value". So you need to play around your logic if you want to use that model like for example average two channels into one to get in total 3 channels.